# Why is my thesis.tex not using my literature.bib file and creates a thesis.bbl file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am struggling with the Bibliography. I am writing my thesis and want to include a .bib but the thesis.tex file is creating a thesis.bbl file.

I do not understand the reason, i am useing `\bibliography{./content/literatur}`  which refers to the literatur.bib file. Where is my mistake?

Thank your for your helps

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\frontmatter
\TitelSeite

\include{./content/erklarung}
\cleardoublepage

%\include{./content/vorwort}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
%%
%% Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%
\tableofcontents
%\listoftodos

\include{./content/einleitung}
\mainmatter
%%
%% eigentliche Kapitel der Arbeit
%%
\include{./content/Kapitel_01}
\include{./content/Kapitel_02}
\include{./content/Kapitel_03}
\include{./content/Kapitel_04}
\include{./content/Kapitel_05}

\clearpage
%%\listoffigures
%\listoftables
%%
%% Anhang
%%
\begin{appendix}
\include{./content/anhang_01}
\end{appendix}
\backmatter
%%
%% Literaturverzeichnis (bitte auskommentieren!)
%%
\bibliography{./content/literatur}
\bibliographystyle{plain}   % Verweise sind Nummern
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}  % Verweise betehen aus Autorennamen und Erscheinungsjahr
\end{document}
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: you have not shown any usable code but you need to run bibtex to generate the bibliography then pdflatex twice more to include it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

Comment: As David says: You need to run BibTeX. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what BibTeX does and how it works in more detail. If you did run BibTeX, there should be a `.blg` file that reports any errors or warnings BibTeX encountered while compiling your document. (Windows may say that the `.blg` file is a "performance monitor file", but it is just a simple text file you can open with any text editor.) Show us the contents of the `.blg` file.

Comment: If your main document is called `thesis.tex`, the expected output of the BibTeX run is in fact a `thesis.bbl`. So if you get that file, things might actually be running as intended. Note that BibTeX only adds entries to the bibliography that were `\cite`d explicitly (or `\nocite`d) in the document. If you have no citation, you will get an empty bibliography. (If you want to add all entries from your `.bib` file without citing them, say `\nocite{*}`.)